# I use await with function before send JSON to client but there is an error

Tags: node.js

Server.js file

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var app     = express();
app.use(express.json());  
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

app.get('/testdb', function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile("/my_project/testdb"+ "/" + "testdb.html" );
});

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
   res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
   res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, 
   Content-Type, Accept");
   next();
});

app.post('/myaction',async function(req, res) {
  var st = req.body.status; 
  async function callServer() {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        var dataJson =  show();
        resolve(dataJson);
     });
}
try {
     if(st != 's') await tdb(req);
    var myJson = await callServer();
} catch(e) {
    throw new Error(e.toString());
}
res.status(200);
res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');

var d = "detail1";
var subj = "subject1";
res.send(JSON.stringify([{ status: st , detail: d , subject: subj },{ 
 status: st , detail: d , subject: subj }]));
});

app.listen(8081, function() {
   console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:8081/');
});
Client 
$.fn.ajaxShow = function(st) {
  xhrct =  $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    dataType: "json",
                    data : {
                          status : st
                          },
                    url: 'http://127.0.0.1:8081/myaction',                      
                    success: function (data) {  
                               if(data!=null) {
                                    var fotoData = data;
                                  $(fotoData).each(function (i, obx) {
                                        alert(obx.status+" , "+obx.detail+" 
                                              , "+obx.subject); 
                                        });
                                      }

                    },
                    error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) 
                    {
                         alert("XMLHttpRequest: 
                         "+XMLHttpRequest.responseText);
                         alert("textStatus: "+textStatus);
                         alert("errorThrown: "+errorThrown);
                     }
                });
   }
```

I send JSON to client but there is an error at client that it alert `XMLHttpRequest.responseText` is null and textStatus is error  and errorThrown is null. I try remove await from `var myJson = await callServer()`; to be `var myJson = callServer();` yes it can work and no error. I want to wait callServer() done  before send JSON to client.What should I do? 
please help me.

Comment: What is the error at the backend and can you please add your show() and tdb() functions?

Comment: @Ashish  at the backend there're not any error

Answer (score 0):

Try to this way

```
app.post('/myaction',async function(req, res) {
  var st = req.body.status; 
  function callServer() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      var dataJson =  show();
      resolve(dataJson);
   });
}
try {
  if(st != 's') await tdb(req);
  var myJson = await callServer();
} catch(e) {
  throw new Error(e.toString());
}
```

[Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) you can find the details

Comment: I've tried  your code but it doesn't work it still has the same problem